# im trying to check if a string is two specific words

Tags: python

I am trying to check if the result of a `raw_input()` in Python contains either 'yes' or 'no'.

```
AddMoney = Raw_input("Do you want to enter any more money")
while AddMoney.lower() != str("yes") and AddMoney.lower() != str("no"):
    AddMoney.lower() == str(raw_input("Please enter a valid input (yes or no)"))
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: do you have closing quote on original code?

Comment: yes @Lafexlos I fixed that now

Comment: You're missing a colon on the `while` condition.

Comment: I was in a rush. I fixed that know @alexwlchan

Comment: Your logic is flawed -- different from "yes" *or* different from "no" will always be true because "yes" is different from "no" and "no" is different from "yes". You want *and* there, not *or*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I fixed that on my code but it still dosent work

Comment: Also, I'm afraid fixing defects in your question as we point them out is not the right thing to do here. Instead, take some time to reflect back on our remarks, leave your question as it is and fix your whole code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the stray quotation mark.

Your code:

```
while AddMoney.lower() != str("yes")"
```

Should be:

```
while AddMoney.lower() != str("yes")
```

And do you have an else condition? You didn't include one in your code. Also there is no colon at the end of your while loop.
**Edit:** I see you've updated your code to reflect this.